# C# - Copying contents of folder from flash drive to System32

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, copy, drive, system32

I am taking on the project of building a program that will copy the contents of a folder on a flash drive to the C:\Windows\system32 folder.

Specifically, three DLL's that are required to run Crystal Reports for my company through Internet Explorer. This would happen under the button_clicked event.

My problem is that the drive letter could change from computer to computer.

So, I suppose I first need to get the drive letter of the flash drive, then copy the contents of this folder to C:\Windows\system32.

Could someone give me a hint as to the most effective way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: So you want to know how to determine the drive letter of the removable flash drive that contains the three files to copy to the System32 directory?

Comment: Are you doing this with Visual Studio by any chance? You can add the dll's to your project and deploy them at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Check [DriveDetector](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program). scroll down the page and look for OnDriveArrived Event mentioned. Go through it and you'll get the answer.